# Call Windows Shell and Pass it some arguments .NET c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shell

Here my problem, I want to use gpg.exe to decrypt some data. Before this, I want to test and make an "ipconfig" through the Windows Shell. I've tried :

> Process.Start("cmd","ipconfig");

without success. Did someone know a way to help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can't you just start ipconfig directly? Have you tried the [ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) flag?

Comment: What means 'without success'? An error? Not the expected result?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this function (taken from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/guystarbuck/archive/2008/02/06/invoking-cmd-exe-from-net.aspx))

```
   public static string ExecuteCmd(string arguments)
    {
        // Create the Process Info object with the overloaded constructor
        // This takes in two parameters, the program to start and the
        // command line arguments.
        // The arguments parm is prefixed with "@" to eliminate the need
        // to escape special characters (i.e. backslashes) in the
        // arguments string and has "/C" prior to the command to tell
        // the process to execute the command quickly without feedback.
        ProcessStartInfo _info =
            new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"/C " + arguments);

        // The following commands are needed to redirect the
        // standard output.  This means that it will be redirected
        // to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        _info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        // Set UseShellExecute to false.  This tells the process to run
        // as a child of the invoking program, instead of on its own.
        // This allows us to intercept and redirect the standard output.
        _info.UseShellExecute = false;

        // Set CreateNoWindow to true, to supress the creation of
        // a new window
        _info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        // Create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        Process _p = new Process();
        _p.StartInfo = _info;
        _p.Start();

        // Capture the results in a string
        string _processResults = _p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        // Close the process to release system resources
        _p.Close();

        // Return the output stream to the caller
        return _processResults;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- The first parameter is the file executed, `"cmd"` is a shortcut for `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd"`.
- The second parameter are the arguments to give to the program. Here, you can't just write `"ipconfig"`. You have to use `/r` or `/c` or `/k` to give the arguments to `cmd`:

  > /c or /r : Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.
  >   /k : Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/r ipconfig");
```

Comment: I beg your pardon, mine was just a doubt :)

Comment: Do you really have to hard-code the full path to cmd.exe? Won't it find it in the system path?

Comment: @Marco: No worries :) In `cmd` help, it is written that `/R is equivalent to /C for compatibility reasons`. I don't know which one is supposed to be used though.

Comment: Thanks it works, can you tell me why the shell disappears as fast as it appears ?

Comment: It's the normal behavior: `/c or /r : Carries out the command specified by string` **and then stops**. Use `/k` instead of `/r` if you don't want the command window to close at the end.

Comment: This is a bit overkill. You can get rid of "cmd" and all its command line switches, and just start "ipconfig" directly.

Comment: THANK YOU. Last question, if the command line passed through the shell send back some data, how can I hear the stream out please ?

Comment: @Jack: See Marco's answer: `_p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the statement

```
ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"/C " + arguments);
```

Contrary to the comment in the code, the `@` sign only affects the string `"/C "` and does not the affect the contents of the string `arguments`. In this case it doesn't hurt anything, but doesn't do anything either.

Contrary to the comment in the code, any `\`s in `arguments` would indeed need to be escaped.